# InnoSetup: trying to Start [Code] section

Tags: installation, inno-setup

For some reason my [Code] section not even run. Example

`[Code]
procedure Test();
begin
    Log('test');
    MsgBox('test!!!', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;`

When I run install.exe file, nothing happen. I suppose that the first line should use Function, not Procedure. What could be the reason?

Comment: This look like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578). We need [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Define function/procedure is not enought to run the function/procedure.

You need also to call the function/procedure.

You can do it for example this way

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep=ssDone then
  begin 
    Test();
  end 
end;
```

More events and examples You can find here:

https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm

https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm

Comment: I call procedure from [Files] Section using BeforeInstall.But it doesn't work
`[Files]`
`Source: Files\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe; DestDir: {app}; Flags: overwritereadonly ignoreversion uninsremovereadonly; BeforeInstall: Test()`

Comment: try
BeforeInstall: Test
Without "()"

Comment: Installation does not reach line in the [Files] section where the BeforeInstall is contained. I think it's wrong way, better use from InitializeSetup function.